# How to increase volume not using a volume button

Tags: volume

My phone was accidentally dropped into a sink full of water. I took it out quickly, and everything was working well apart from two buttons:

1. Windows button which is ok because I can use back button
2. Increase volume button.

I can't increase volume of my phone now... Is there any way to increase volume not using a button?

The phone I am using is Samsung i766

**Edit**

After 4-5 days the buttons started working again!

Comment: How long have you dried it out for? Might take a while to remove all of the moisture.

Comment: 27 hours right now. There were also charging problem which now come back to normal, so charging is working properly.

Comment: Personally I would still try to make sure it is completely dried out before charging or turning it on. If you didn't already, then consider placing the phone in a bowl of rice http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/how-to/tips/4269047

Comment: Thanks for advice, it seems to be very helpful, unfortunately I still can't use increase volume button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1

Go to diagnosis mode with calling at that number `##634#`. Then on diagnostics type `*#0673#` it will play music automatically restoring volume

Solution #2

Go to diagnosis mode with calling at that number `##634#`. Then on diagnostics type `*#0*#` then tap `MelodyRecv` it will play music automatically restoring volume